# Hermite polynomial after rotation

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, gaussian, machine-learning

When we consider the $n$-dimensional standard normal distribution, the orthogonal basis is $\{H_S(x)\}_{S}$ where $H_S(x) = \prod_{k=1}^n H_{s_k}(x_k)$. Here $H_*(x)$ is the normalized probabilist's hermite polynomial. Suppose $U$ is any real orthogonal matrix. How to express $H_S(Ux)$ in terms of $\{H_S(x)\}_{S}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expansion coefficients of a function $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n)$ in the rotated basis of Hermite polynomials are related to the original expansion coefficients by an orthogonal matrix of "steering coefficients". Explicit expressions for $n=1,2,3$ are given in section 3.6 of K.L. Reynolds, [Convolution, Rotation, and Data Fusion with Orthogonal Expansions](https://jscholarship.library.jhu.edu/bitstream/handle/1774.2/60082/REYNOLDS-DISSERTATION-2018.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y). See also [Accurate Image Rotation using Hermite Expansions.](http://europepmc.org/backend/ptpmcrender.fcgi?accid=PMC2837196&blobtype=pdf)